# Measure for the probability that a criteria (a subevent) is fulfilled conditional on an event (the mainevent) happening

Tags: correlation, association-measure

Suppose I have a list of events over years. In this list multiple events can happen in the same year and for each event there are several characteristics / criteria. For example, you could have elections at the municipal level (events) and criteria (election won in 1st round with a candidate receiving more than 50% votes). Is there type of correlation coefficient for these types of data? I want to make a statement about the probability that a criteria is fulfilled conditional on the event happening.

Example dataset for R:

```
structure(list(year = c(1997, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 200), events = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), event.characteristic = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Why not just use the observed frequency of the criterion being fulfilled conditional on the event happening as an estimate?   Without much data, it won't be very accurate, but without much data, nothing will be all that accurate.  There are better methods, but as a start...

Comment: Yes, I did that! I am intrigued about the better methods though! :)